# Code::Blocks failing to load a project?

Tags: c++, c, ide, codeblocks

Each time I load Code::Blocks by double clicking my Code::Blocks project file it opens up Code::Blocks and the window blinks a bit once it loads, but then it's like it didn't load anything, it acts like I didn't open any project. It also does this if I do *File -> Open*. What should I do? I already tried to re-install it. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behaviour of code blocks, when you double click your project file (.cbp) notice the title bar, if it shows the name of your project, it means project is open, and the blank window means that you haven't opened any files of the project yet, open them using file->open.